# How to improve SQL query performance using varchar columns in Join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have this query as dummy one which explain my scenario correctly, where I need to perform join using `Varchar(500)` columns also query contains joins.

I have checked with index and its correct. The query taking more than 15 minutes.

The query also has to combine 2 column values in `Select` clause as one column and have `Where` condition for same.

Can anyone provide some advice for this?

possible data for firstname is numeric and in Lastname its string which may contain plain text or the text which contain some special characters like () / . , & - etc.

Below is the example of my query

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         FirstName + '(' + LastName + ')'  as fullname
     from 
         User u 
     inner join 
         CompanyUser c on c.FirstName = u.FirstName 
                       and c.LastName = u.LastName
    ) a
where 
    fullname  = 'abc(def)'
```

Comment: This is not a incorrect question, as I can not give the actual query because of its project related, so I have added the example which interpret query in which I have issue, and now I am trying to split the data at C# level and pass it to query as parameter, please remove that negative vote from the question

Comment: It's not my downvote, but people are tree to vote as they please without explanation - you just need to get used to it

Comment: As for the question, the problem with it is, SQL is a declarative language i.e. with your query you are specifying the results you want, but the query itself does not tell us how the database engine chose to retrieve those results. For that we need to see the actual execution plan. Unfortunately for these kinds of question it's next to impossible to help with a simplified version of the query because it's unlikely to have the same performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select u.FirstName + '(' + u.LastName + ')'  as fullname
from Users u
inner join CompanyUser c
  on substring('abc(def)',1,charindex('(','abc(def)')-1)=c.FirstName
   and substring('abc(def)',charindex('(','abc(def)')+1
       ,charindex(')','abc(def)')-charindex('(','abc(def)')-1)=c.LastName
   and c.FirstName=u.FirstName and c.LastName=u.LastName
```

clustered index on Users and CompanyUser (FirstName,LastName) - necessarily.

Server calculates `substring('abc(def)',1,charindex('(','abc(def)')-1)` as constant on query compiling or before JOIN. Just,UI data like 'abc(def)' mast be parsed on UI side;)

Table name `User` - causes strong doubt, even for an example.

With parameters:

```
declare @param varchar(50);
select @param='abc(def)';

declare @FirstName varchar(50);
declare @LastName varchar(50);
select @FirstName=substring(@param,1,charindex('(',@param)-1)
select @LastName=substring(@param,charindex('(',@param)+1
       ,charindex(')',@param)-charindex('(',@param)-1)
-- next case when param like 'abc(de(f))  or *(*)
-- @firstName from 1 symbol to before first '('
-- @lastName after first '(' and before last symbol
-- Example '123aa_(@#$%#$^^)' --> '123aa_'  and '@#$%#$^^'
-- commonly *(*)
select @LastName=substring(@param,charindex('(',@param)+1
       ,len(@param)-charindex('(',@param)-1)

select u.FirstName + '(' + u.LastName + ')'  as fullname
from Users u
inner join CompanyUser c
  on c.FirstName=@FirstName  and c.LastName=@LastName
   and c.FirstName=u.FirstName and c.LastName=u.LastName
```

Upd1. Change parsing.  Presume that FirstName do not  contain '('.

Upd2. If you parse parameters in C#, query is simple

```
select u.FirstName + '(' + u.LastName + ')'  as fullname
from Users u
inner join CompanyUser c
  on c.FirstName=@FirstName  and c.LastName=@LastName
   and c.FirstName=u.FirstName and c.LastName=u.LastName
```

Going back to performance.

I think,  `User JOIN CompanyUser` operation takes most of the time. The application of the condition `c.FirstName=@FirstName  and c.LastName=@LastName` should significantly reduce the volume of this operation. However, this requires an index on (FirstName,LastName) for both tables. I think it will be better than separate indexes (FirstName) and (LastName).
It is interesting to test these hypotheses.

It will be interesting to look at your measurements with different queries. I would like to see the query performance using different examples and query execution plans.

Comment: What if my value is like 'abc(de(f))' here 'abc' is firstname and 'de(f)' is lastname.
I have tried with the Parameter approach, but it return incorrect value for LastName

Comment: `` 'de(f)'`` as LastName? surprise.  Explain,pls, possible structures for FirstName(Lastname). For ``FirstName + '(' + LastName + ')'  as fullname`` LastName contains '(' or ')' ?

Comment: Answer updated for case value is like 'abc(de(f))'

Comment: I have edited the Question, can you please check, where I have mention all possible data

Comment: Answer is updated. Try,pls.

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing it to be slow. Also you are doing an unnecessary join (that query wouldn't run as is anyway). Be sure you have indexes on Firstname and Lastname in both tables (a clustered index on lastname, firstname would be good).

```
select 
         FirstName + '(' + LastName + ')'  as fullname
from User u 
     where exists (select * from 
         CompanyUser c where c.FirstName = u.FirstName 
                       and c.LastName = u.LastName
    )
where 
    Lastname = 'def' and FirstName  = 'abc';
```

Comment: From UI I will get value as 'abc(def)' and in lastname we can have value with round bracket, so I can not add condition for Lastname and Firstname column

Comment: @S.Deshmukh I suggest you split that value on the UI side and pass to SQL as separate parameters

Comment: @S.Deshmukh, you can simply split the value on client side and pass firstName, lastName separate. KISS (Keep It Simple Sam).

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked for execution plan?
You dont need to use a subquery in this query and you should use concat_ws function instead of + operator.
Clustered index is not suitable for name and surname columns. Use nonclustered index.

Comment: why? is it faster??

Comment: `+` functions perfectly fine to concatenate strings and what would be the separator you would use with `concat_ws()` here?

Comment: @d00lar, Yes i think so but most important thing is the clustered index design considerations. You can find in this topic: 
Yes i think so but most important thing is the clustered index design considerations. You can find in this topic: https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-effective-sql-server-clustered-indexes/

Comment: @Stu, i would use space

Comment: There is no space in the OP's data.

Comment: @Stu, ah yes. Okay then concat works fine here. But space looks better if it possible

Comment: What makes you think clustered index is not suitable for this? Do you know for sure that it is not the operation that OP needs most?

Comment: Why one should use concat_ws() instead of + ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).